# Setting viewonly and scale with vncserver-x11-serviced

Tags: raspbian-stretch, vnc

I'm trying to get the VNC server to start in viewonly mode with a scale of 0.25x0.25 but can't see exactly where this has to be set.

It looks like in older versions you would start VNC with the -viewonly switch etc but /usr/bin/vncserver-x11-serviced doesn't take these options.  I've tried adding configuration to the /etc/vnc/config.d/common.custom along with my working authentication setting but it doesn't have any effect.  Can anyone advise where to put this configuration or even better point to the documentation that specifies how to do it?